# Creating polygons that share the boundaries of existing polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon, trace, create

I'm creating polygon (that about actual vegetation).

First, I create one polygon

[image]

After that, I will create more polygons that share the boundaries of existing polygon.
But, it show result like below image.

[image]

How can I create polygons that share the boundaries of existing polygons.

And last, can I use trace method for creating polygon in QGIS?

Comment: Which version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: 2.18.17 version

Answer (score 2):

**In QGis 3.x**

1. Enable the *snapping toolbar* and open *snapping settings*. Then, choose the *advanced configuration* and select your layer of interest
   [image]
2. Go to Add Feature and start digitizing. When you will be close to a vertex, you should see a particular color
3. When you are done, I suggest you to [check the topology](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_topology_checker.html)

Answer (score 1):

To create polygons that shares boundaries with existing ones,

**In QGis 2.x**

1. Settings > snapping options > choose advanced and select your layer.
   Then define the snapping mode, the tolerance and your units
   [image]
2. Go to Add Feature and start digitizing. When you will be close to a vertex, you should see a particular color
3. When you are done, I suggest you to [check the topology](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_topology_checker.html)
4. As the trace method, you may see [Freehand Editing](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/freehandEditing/) useful

Answer (score 1):

This digitising method might help:

1. Set **Avoid Intersections** ON as mentioned above.
2. Start digitising at a shared vertex or segment – digitise vertices that are not shared
3. Continue digitising
4. When you reach the last non-shared vertex – digitise a shared vertex
5. Then to finish digitise a last point – but make sure that it is located in a place that ensures the polygon extends over all shared vertices – right click to finish digitsing the polygon.
   [image: Digiting method]

QGIS will create all the vertices for the new polygon as shown below
[[image: completed polygon with shared boundary[2]]